# Falling back on PROMPT mode since _cordovaNative is missing. Expected for Android 3.2 and lower only. in cordova v- 3.3.1

Tags: android, jquery, cordova

I am using cordova version - 3.3.1 for develop an application and getting this error "Falling back on PROMPT mode since _cordovaNative is missing. Expected for Android 3.2 and lower only." How can i get this error as i am using 3.3.1

```
function file_transfer(){

    var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
    var uri = "http://headerlabs.com/images/iphone.png";

    fileTransfer.download(
        uri,
        function(entry) {
            console.log("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
        },
        function(error) {
            console.log("download error source " + error.source);
            console.log("download error target " + error.target);
            console.log("upload error code" + error.code);
        },
        false,
        {

        }
    );  
    }
```

I am using cordova file,file-transfer plugin for download the file and this is code for downloading the file

Answer (score 0):

This error is related to the Android version (3.2 or lower) and has nothing to do with the cordova version you're running.